# updateSelectInput is overwritten by a selectInput in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, selectinput

In the example below the action button would update the select input values. However, the second selection input is dependent on the first one and when the action button is selected the update to "virginica" does not occur.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

        actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "click"),
        uiOutput("select_col"),
        uiOutput("select_species")
    
    )
    
    #
    server <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$select_col <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "select_col", 
                label = "select_col", 
                choices = colnames(iris))
    })
    
    output$select_species <- renderUI({
        selectInput(inputId = "select_species",
                label = "Species",
                choices = unique(iris[ ,input$select_col]))
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$action, {
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_col", selected = "Species")
        updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_species", selected = "virginica")
    })
    
    }
    
    # Run the application 
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect the following result:
'Species'in selectinput 'select_col' and setosa in selectinput 'Species'

Comment: you didn't type the correct input ID

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, I fixed it, but  I still need to double click on action button to have the expected result.

Comment: Ah I see the problem now. I would include a second observer: `observeEvent(input$select_col, { # second update input here })`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, this is the best solution so far, but it will trigger the update without the user clicking the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```r
  xxx <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_col", selected = "Species")
    xxx(TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(xxx(), {
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_species", selected = "virginica")
    xxx(NULL)
  })
```

---

## EDIT

No that doesn't work. Here is a solution using the `delay` function of the **shinyjs** package:

```r
  observeEvent(input$action, {
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_col", selected = "Species")
    delay(0, updateSelectInput(inputId = "select_species", selected = "virginica"))
  })
```

Don't forget:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), # <- don't forget that
  actionButton(inputId = "action", label = "click"),
  ......
```

Comment: Hi @StéphaneLaurent, it didn't work.

Comment: @VanderSouza I see: there's a delay caused by the `renderUI`. Observe that it works if you click two times. Let me think more about this problem.